# Redux-persist how to persist some state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

Everyone  i have been using redux-persist  for a  while now and is really  a great  tool,  but the problem  is that  it just persist all  my states  (reducers), i will like to  know is there  is a way to  choose  which states are  to  be persist.
Thanks

Comment: Look into the 'whitelist' config option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your redux-persist config you can add a `whitelist` or `blacklist` depending on your need. These take an array of the states you would like to include (whitelist) or ignore (blacklist).

For example:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  blacklist: ['state-not-to-be-persisted']
}
```

[Official documentation](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist)